# Not seeing engagement index option when adding activities

Tags: activities, activity

I'm not seeing an option to set engagement index when trying to add activities?
Do I need to enable it somewhere first?

Comment: if you weren't using civicampaign the alternative might be just to make yourself a custom field - i don't quite recall what benefits Engagement Index offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the permissions fixed this.
Needed to add permissions for civicampaign
When I was not seeing the engagement index in activities it was when I was logged in as a user who didn't have campaign permissions.

Answer (score 3):

For the engagement index to show you need to have CiviCampaign enabled. For details on how to set up the index and other useful guidance you can also see the latest user guide

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/civic-engagement/everyday-tasks/#using-the-engagement-index

Hopefully it's just as simple as that to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I have enables civicampaign and I'm still not seeing the option when adding activities.

Comment: Oh shame. You could amend your original question to include your version of Civi and CMS and maybe screenshots if possible as that may help someone else to provide further guidance.

Comment: Not sure what changed but logged in today and had engagement index there.
Probably just forgot to reload cache

Answer (score 1):

From docs

> You can record an Engagement Index for the following activities or actions: Phone Call, Meeting or Interview.

Are you trying to do this for other Activity Types?

Comment: No.
Just those types.